# Infinite balls, infinite groups with finite number of balls of each value

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, limits

You have N balls of value 0, N of value 1, N of value 2, etc., N of each value up to infinity.

They are separated into a group of X balls with total value 1, another group of X with total value 2, another of X with value 3, etc., one different group of X for each total value up to infinity.

What is the smallest N for X=4 to be possible? What is the general equation for any value X?

Comment: Are the balls replaced back into the box?

Comment: I don't quite understand what your question is. If at each "step", you're just removing $1$ or $4$ balls then clearly doing this up to $k$ will just require $k$ or $4k$ steps. What are you defining a "step" to be, for it to depend on $N$?

Comment: Step k is the removal of 4 balls totalling k in value. The total removed is the sum of all the steps as no balls are returned.

Answer (score 1):

We can show that $N\ge X^2$. Indeed, for any natural $k$ consider a union $U$ of the first $kN$ groups. The sum $S$ of ball’s values of $U$ is $\sum_{i=1}^{kN} i=\frac 12 kN(kN+1).$
On the other hand, for each $j$, $U$ contains at most $N$ balls with value $j$. Since $|U|=kX\cdot N$, we have $S\ge N\sum_{j=0}^{kX-1} j=\frac 12 N(kX-1)kX.$ Thus $$\frac 12 kN(kN+1)\ge \frac 12 N(kX-1)kX$$ or $kN+1\ge kX^2-X$. Since this inequality hold for all $k$, we have $N\ge X^2$.

Comment: do you have an upper bound to go with this lower bound?

Comment: @BenFranks Unortunately, no. I think it should be obtained by a different way, maybe by come combinatorial constructions.